# vsftpd: ftp: setsockopt (ignored): Permission denied

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, unix, vsftpd

I'm trying to upload things to my server however I'm unable to ls inside a directory or upload a file to it.

I'm using CentOS 8, SELinux set on permisssive. The directory I want to operate on has 777 permissions set. The user I'm using is not listed in user_list or ftpusers. I further tried to chown the directory to the user I'm using. None of that worked.

Result of 'put'

```
---> TYPE I
200 Switching to Binary mode.
ftp: setsockopt (ignored): Permission denied
---> PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (-,-,-,-,63,76).
```

Result of 'ls'

```
ftp: setsockopt (ignored): Permission denied
---> PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (-,-,-,-,125,59).
```

vsftpd.conf

```
userlist_deny=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the directory /var/run/vsftpd/empty. I needed to created it for version 3.0 - otherwise it generates the socket error and it doesn't work. I've never used that directory anything. Your mileage may vary depending on the version of vsftpd.